# Derivative of $(XAX^T)^{-1}$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Let $X$ is a rectangular matrix with full row rank, $A$ is positive definite.

How can I find the derivative of $$(XAX^T)^{-1}$$

with respect to $X$.

Comment: Derivative with respect to what?

Comment: Might get some ideas here https://atmos.washington.edu/~dennis/MatrixCalculus.pdf

Comment: I have updated the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the matrix-valued function
$$F=(XAX^T)^{-1}$$
its differential is easy to find.
$$\eqalign{
 I &= FF^{-1} \cr
 0 &= F\,dF^{-1}+dF\,F^{-1} \cr
dF &= -F\,dF^{-1}\,F \cr
   &= -F\,dX\,AX^TF - FXA\,dX^T\,F \cr
}$$
A difficult issue is that the matrix-by-matrix gradient, i.e. $\frac{\partial F}{\partial X}$, is not a matrix but a 4th order tensor. One way to proceed is to [vectorize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) all of the matrix quantities.
$$\eqalign{
df &= -\Big((F^TXA^T\otimes F) + (F^T\otimes FXA)K\Big)\,dx \cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= -(F^TXA^T\otimes F) - (F^T\otimes FXA)K \cr
}$$
where $K$ is the [commutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix) associated with the Kronecker product (represented by $\otimes$).

Comment: If $A$ is a symmetric matrix, then is this derivative symmetric?

Comment: Since $X$ is a _rectangular_  matrix, the shape of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is also rectangular. But only _square_ matrices can be symmetric.